# use localStorage and remove just one row from a dataTable

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi im trying to remove just one row from my Table

[image]

when i click add Line it adds to my table with this code:

```
let items = localStorage.values.dataLocalStorage ?? [];

items.push(
  { id       : Date.now()
  , Name     : select4.selectedLabel
  , Quantity : numberInput1.value
  , Added_by : current_user.id
  })
return items
```

but i want to delete one row when i click delete button of that row only.

I tried this code onclick:

```
let items = localStorage.values.dataLocalStorage ?? [];
return items.filter(item => item.id == table4.selectedRow.data.id);
```

but is not working

what im doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: Try and add a working example

Comment: `localStorage.values.dataLocalStorage` doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Name: 'test',
    Quantity: 10,
    Added_by: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Name: 'test',
    Quantity: 10,
    Added_by: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Name: 'test',
    Quantity: 10,
    Added_by: 1,
  }
]

// i want to remove record id = 2

const findDeleteRecordIndex = data.findIndex((element) =>{
  return element.id === 2
})

data.splice(findDeleteRecordIndex, 1)
console.log('finalData -->', data)
```